# How to set the ListModel of a JList in Netbeans?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, netbeans, jlist

I have designed a Swing GUI with the help of Netbeans IDE and this GUI contains a JList.

Bydefault, it uses AbstractListModel to pass it as an argument in the JList contructor to create that JList.

I want to specify somewhere in the Netbeans to pass DefaultListModel as the model to be passed in that JList so that later I can retrieve it to make changes in the listModel.

How can I do that.

Answer (score 11):

You have two ways of doing this:

1) In your code manually call list.setModel() anywhere after initComponents() is called.
2) Do it through NetBeans - Right click the list, go to "Customize Code".  The first code section is the list's constructor call.  Change the dropdown from "Default Code" to "Custom Creation" and simply insert your ListModel in the constructor call.  You can do this by setting it to new

```
javax.swing.JList(new DefaultListModel())
```

or by instantiating your listmodel before the call to initComponents() in the code and then doing

```
javax.swing.JList(defaultModel);
```

Comment: why after initComponents() and not before?

Comment: It's been awhile, but I believe it was because the JList isn't actually instantiated until initComponents() is called.

Answer (score 6):

I usually do this way in Netbeans
1. Select the **JList**
2. In **model** property, select **Custom code** and insert the *listModel name* (declared in 3rd step)
3. declare `DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();` in code view
4. change listModel declaration to accept a List or similar